# Cant update language in Open Cart

Tags: opencart

In Open Cart I has 2 languages of front page but when I try to change something from second language I cant do it remains the same as the first language. I try to change something from language files but it doesn't works
Please help

I had this datepicker

```
$_['datepicker']            = 'en-gb';
$_['datepicker']            = 'ro';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs to review subdirectories

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).